# Are there limitations to how often I can concuss my opponent?

Tags: divekick

In DiveKick, headshots (when your foot connects with the opponents head) are supposed to put them into a concussed state. (Limited movement/dick and kick).

However, sometimes headshots don't give the opponent a concussion (at least in my experience playing lately). Are there limits to how many consecutive rounds this can happen? Or any other prohibiting factors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [Mr. N's](http://divekick.wikia.com/wiki/Mr._N) neck pillow protects him against one headshot per fight.

> Mr. N's neck pillow protects him from one head shot every fight, preventing him from going into the concussed state that would normally follow a headshot. However, any subsequent head shots in the fight will concuss him as normal.
>   <sub>- [Divekick Wiki - Mr. N](http://divekick.wikia.com/wiki/Mr._N)</sub>

Mr. N is the only character who can cancel a headshot. Once his neck pillow is removed, there are no limits to how many times you can headshot him.

[image: Mr N. with his neck pillow]